# The logarithmic derivative of a twisted L-function?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions

Let $F$ be a quadratic number field with class number $h_F = 1$. Let $\zeta_F$ be the Dedekind zeta function, we have
$$ \frac{\zeta_F ' (1+it)}{\zeta_F (1+it)} \ll \frac{\log t}{\log\log t} .$$
(I don't know how to prove it.)

**My question is:**  I want to consider the $L$-function twisted by the Grossencharacter $\lambda^m (n) = \left( \frac{n}{|n|}\right) ^{m}$, which is defined by
$$ L(s,\lambda ^m) = \sum_{(n)\neq 0} \lambda ^m(n) |n|^{-2s}.$$

I need some bound of
$$ \frac{L' (1+it,\lambda^m)}{L (1+it,\lambda^m)}. $$

Is there a place where I can directly find this bound? Actually I only need a rough estimate, something like
$$ \frac{L' (1+it,\lambda^m)}{L (1+it,\lambda^m)}\ll \log(t^2 + m^2). $$
Can I prove it directly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can prove this directly by combining equations (5.27) and (5.28) of Iwaniec-Kowalski.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thank you very much!